# Xamarin Forms Automation Id for toolbaritems

Tags: xamarin.forms, automated-tests, appium

We are building Test Automation with Appium and we need to add Unique Identifiers for elements we are interacting with. We have achieved this through adding AutomationId property to the XAML file.

This works fine except for Toolbaritems. The added AutomationId is not visible as content-desc for the elements.

```
<core:AppBaseContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem AutomationId="Button1" BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference this}}" Parent="{x:Reference this}"
             Text="{extensions:Translate Button1}"
             Command="{Binding Button1Command}" />
```

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: `ToolbarItem` should have an `AutomationId`. Is the problem that you can't access it while running the test?

Comment: Yes, `AutomationId` which is set in the XAML is displayed for all elements **except** for elements created from `ToolbarItems`class. I cannot access the element when running the test or when inspecting the element with uiautomatorviewer or Appium Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The AutomationId for ToolbarItems doesn't work (at least on Android), but you can identify them using the text property.

```
<NavigationPage.ToolbarItems>
    <controls:BindableToolbarItem 
                 AutomationId="ToolbarButtonHelp"
                 Text="ToolbarButtonHelp"
                 Icon="help" 
                 Priority="0" 
                 Order="Primary"
                 IsVisible="{Binding ToolbarService.IsHelpVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Command="{Binding ToolbarService.HelpCommand}"/>

    <controls:BindableToolbarItem                   
                 AutomationId="ToolbarButtonMenu"
                 Text="ToolbarButtonMenu"
                 Icon="quick_menu" 
                 Priority="1" 
                 Order="Primary"
                 IsVisible="{Binding ToolbarService.IsMenuVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Command="{Binding ToolbarService.MenuCommand}"/>

</NavigationPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Example Xamarin UI Test

```
this.app.WaitForNoElement("ToolbarButtonHelp");
```